# Did weapons export make america powerful?

Tags: international-trade, free-trade

As per the reuters report [america made 130 billions from weapons export](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-weapons-exports-decreased-21-1382-billion-fiscal-2021-2021-12-22/#:%7E:text=U.S.%20weapons%20exports%20decreased%2021%25%20to%20%24138.2%20billion%20in%20fiscal%202021,-By%20Mike%20Stone)Its the revenue so i can understand that the profits will be much lower. For a county like America which spend trillions in federal budget  this billions are small ,right??

Am i calculating this wrong??

There are allegations that the west grew because of exporting weapons but i think its just a myth.ofcourse they are companies that make profit from this but this didn't fuel americas growth,which is much more complicated and deserves to a lot credits to other factors.

Also explain the lobbying powers of weapons exporters.How much money in lobbying are we talking here?? Are there any revelations regarding this?? Any whistle blowers??

I am willing to change my view if i got the right answer

Comment: One useful comparison is with [US total exports](https://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/statistics/highlights/AnnualPressHighlights.pdf), which in 2021 were \$2,528 billion.  So \$138 billion military equipment exports in 2021, which is what your link shows, would be c 5%.

Comment: How do you want to measure how powerful country is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.